Spotify WebAPI RefreshToken Request Error
I wanted to create a request to get the RefreshToken of a user. The problem is that I got the HTTP Error 400. I changed this code from an already existing code where everything worked normally with the only difference, that it gave me the AccessToken.
public void getTokens() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(accessTokenURL);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            
        String authHeader = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((clientID + ":" + clientSecret).getBytes());
        http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authHeader);
    
        String data = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURL;
    
        byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
        OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(out);
    
        BufferedReader Lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
        String currentLine = Lines.readLine();
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while (currentLine != null) {
            response.append(currentLine).append("\n");
            currentLine = Lines.readLine();
        }
    
        this.accessToken = String.valueOf(new JsonParser().parse(String.valueOf(response)).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("access_token"));
        this.refreshToken = String.valueOf(new JsonParser().parse(String.valueOf(response)).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("refresh_token"));
        this.expiresIn = String.valueOf(new JsonParser().parse(String.valueOf(response)).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("expires_in"));
            
        http.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

I have tested it with the curl command to see if the entries are wrong. Everything worked there.
I replaced POST with GET once, but it still didn't work. (The Spotify docs it mentioned that you have to use POST)
I tried to get the RefreshToken from the user. With a similar code I managed to get an AccessToken to make requests to the platform. Just not for a user. (As already mentioned above)
